# How to use an image address in a key value pair in next/image?

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js

I'm trying to figure out how to reference an image in a react app that uses Next.js.  When I directly reference the image in the Image component - by reference to the name of the import file, I can render the image, however, I am trying to use an array, which has an image key value pair in it. I cannot find the format that I need to use to be able to use the import name in the key value pair.

I have:

```
import Image from 'next/image'

import bpstar from '../images/logos/bpstar.png'



const faqs = [
  [
    {
      status: 'working on it',
      image: "bpstar"

    },

{faqs.map((column, columnIndex) => (
            <li key={columnIndex}>
              <ul role="list" className="space-y-10">
                {column.map((faq, faqIndex) => (
                  <li key={faqIndex}>

 {faq.image !== "" && (
                            <Image
                              src={faq.image}
                              alt="_"
                              width={80}
                              height={80}
                            />
                          )}
```

If I replace the src line in the Image tag with:  src={bpstar}, the image renders. I can't find a syntax that works with this going through the faq array.

Answer (score 0):

In the faq array, the prop image: bpstar doesn't have "" around it